# PHP - why is_dir returns TRUE when a dir doesn't exist?

Tags: php

My current directory structure is as follows:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP_Upload_Image_MKDIR
```

In other words, the following directories do NOT exist at all.

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP_Upload_Image_MKDIR\uploaded
C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP_Upload_Image_MKDIR\uploaded\s002
```

The problem is that when I run the following script, the function is_dir always return TRUE.

Based on the manual, https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php
is_dir: Returns TRUE if the filename exists and is a directory, FALSE  otherwise.

Do I miss something here?

Thank you

> ```
> $userID = 's002';
> $uploadFolder = '/PHP_Upload_Image_MKDIR/uploaded/';
> $userDir = $uploadFolder . $userID;
> echo '<br/>$userDir: ' . $userDir . '<br/>';
>
> if ( is_dir ($userDir))
> {
>   echo "dir exists"; // always hit here!!!
> }
> else 
> {
>   echo "dir doesn't exist";
> }
>
> mkdir($userDir, 0700);
> ```

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP_Upload_Image_MKDIR>dir /ah
 Volume in drive C is System
 Volume Serial Number is 30B8-2BB2

 Directory of C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP_Upload_Image_MKDIR

File Not Found

C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP_Upload_Image_MKDIR>


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Based on Artefacto's comments:

```
Here is the output of C:\PHP_Upload_Image_MKDIR\uploaded\s005
 echo '<br/>' . realpath($userDir) . '<br/>';
```

Thank you for the solutions.

Best wishes

Comment: Are you positive that those directories don't exist (eg: they could be hidden)

Comment: ya, make sure the directory isn't there ... the code works fine with me

Comment: see what's the result of `realpath($userDir)`

Comment: Also, are you sure that this is not a caching issue? `Note: The results of this function are cached. See clearstatcache() for more details.` can you try with a new, unique directory name just to make sure?

Comment: This is a good point Pekka, you should have made an answer.

Comment: @Pekka No, that would be the other issue, when always returning `FALSE` even after the directory is really created. How it could cached `TRUE` at all if the dir does not exist?

Comment: Hello Artefacto,

Please post your comments as an answer and I will vote for it as the final solution.

Thank you

This is the problem:
C:\PHP_Upload_Image_MKDIR\uploaded\s005

Comment: @q0987 Accept efritz's instead, he got the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also, it seems as if the dir you are checking is `PHP_Uploaded_Image_MKDIR/uploaded/s002`, which is an absolute path starting from the root filesystem.

Try prepending `C:\xampp\htdocs\` to this and see if it works then.  Also, check to see if the folder exists at the root of the volume.

Answer (score 2):

Try file_exists() instead.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

Answer (score 2):

If you've run that script more than once, then `is_dir($userDir)` will return `true` because of this line (the last one) in your script:

```
mkdir($userDir, 0700);
```

You can use [**rmdir()**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php) or some other method to delete it.

To test `is_dir()`, try a directory name that has never been used / created. Something like the following should return false, when it does, you know that `is_dir()` works:

```
if ( is_dir ("/PHP_Upload_Image_MKDIR/uploaded/lkjlkjlkjkl"))
```